# setTimeout inside ForEach does not wait with the specific ms given

Tags: javascript, loops, time, foreach, delay

ForEach console.log's very fast. But i need it to wait every 8sec before console.log the next item in Set. I tried setTimeout but it doesn't seem to console.log at the specific ms given.

```
const completedIds = [];

//Dom mutation observer
const observeChat = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList) {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {


      for (i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
mutation.addedNodes[i].firstChild.naturalWidth < 51 ? pm(mutation.addedNodes[i].firstChild.src.slice(-48, -12)) : false
      }
      
    }
  }
});
observeChat.observe(document.querySelector('.accounts-container__list'), {attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: false});

// Pm function
pm = ids => {
  observeChat.disconnect();
  if (!completedIds.includes(ids)) {
    const img = new Set().add(ids).forEach(function(id, index) {
      setTimeout(function() { // Not working. Does NOT print in console every 8sec
        console.log(id)
      }, index * 8000)
    })
  }
  observeChat.observe(document.querySelector('.accounts-container__list'), {attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: false});
}
```

Comment: You didn't set it to log *every* 8s, but *after* 8s.

Comment: I mean. I need it to wait every 8sec before it moves on to next item in set.

Comment: What actually happens? Also timeouts/intervals are not accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

1. You're creating a `Set` with only one entry in it. `add` doesn't spread out entries you give it. If you're giving it an array, you're getting a set with just that array in it. I suspect you wanted to spread it out.
2. The "indexes" of a set are the same as its values, so `index * 8000` will try to multiply the ID you just added by 8000. It's not an index like the one array's `forEach` gives you.
3. `img` will always be `undefined`, because the return value of [`Set.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach) is `undefined`.

I suspect you're using `Set` to get unique values. If so, you want to:

1. Use `new Set(...ids)` to create the set, and
2. Convert it back to an array before using `forEach`
3. Intialize `img` in some other way. It's not clear to me what it's meant to be, so I can't help with that part...

Something along these lines:

```
    [...new Set(ids)].forEach(function(id, index) {
//  ^^^^−−−−−−−^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− here
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(id);
        }, index * 8000);
    });
```

Live Example:

```js
const ids = ["a", "b", "c"];
[...new Set(ids)].forEach(function(id, index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(id, new Date());
    }, index * 8000);
});
```

Alternatively, you could use a `for-of` loop with a counter:

```
let index = 0;
for (const id of [...new Set(ids)]) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(id);
    }, index++ * 8000);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let index = 0;
for (const id of [...new Set(ids)]) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(id);
    }, index++ * 8000);
}
```